# Change the filename of a plotly file downloaded from a shiny app which is opened in a browser

Tags: r, download, shiny, plotly

I have the simple shiny app below which I open in browser. This is essential. Then I download this plot via the download icon that plotly provides but I would like to know if instead of the file name "newplot" that is set by default I could set the downloaded file name of my choice.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("event")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # renderPlotly() also understands ggplot2 objects!
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt)
  })

  output$event <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_hover")
    if (is.null(d)) "Hover on a point!" else d
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the config:

```
plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y = ~wt) %>%      
config(plot_ly(),
toImageButtonOptions= list(filename = 'your_name',
                           width = 1000,
                           height =  350))
```

See also https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js